# Opnennes of two similar sets

Tags: general-topology, elementary-set-theory

So we have the following sets, and the question is whether they are open (to be more specific, this is asked to show using concepts of relative topology).

Note that $\overline{B} = \{b=(b1,b2) \in \mathbb{R^2} : d(b,0) \leq 1 \}$

The sets: $A = \{(x,y) \in \overline{B} : xy > 0\}$ and $A' = \{(x,y) \in \overline{B} : xy \geq 0 \}$

Ditching the part where we use concepts of relative topology, can't we just pick $a=(1/\sqrt{2}, 1/\sqrt{2})$, so that $d(a,0)=1$, meaning $a \in A$ and $a \in A'$. Now if we pick any $B(a,r) = \{b'=(b1',b2') \in \mathbb{R^2} : d(a,b') <r \}$, for example $b'=(1/\sqrt{2},1/\sqrt{2}+r/2)$, we instantly see that $d(b,a) > 1$ and hence that this ball is in neither of these sets (A and A'). And so that neither is an open set. Right?

Also any tips on how to approach this using concepts from relative topology would be appreciated...

Comment: Since you ask about concepts of relative topology it would be interesting to know what the overall topological space(s) is (are). Your point $a$ shows that neither sets are open in $\mathbb{R}^2$, to show that they are not open in $\overline B$ you would have to consider open balls *in* $\overline B$, i.e. sets of the form $B(a,r)\cap \overline B$. (Btw. $A$ is open in $\overline B$)

Comment: Hi!
Oh, that's true, I wasn't being very specific. 
And you seemed to point out the interesting part right away. Indeed, the original question was about these sets being open in $\overline{B}$. [The teacher actually had forgotten writing that into the assignment - that's probably what got me confused. Luckily, the same task was found in the textbook.]

And that's true, I think I can see (at least from the definition of openness) why A is open in $\overline{B}$. 

And the topological space is just $\mathbb{R^2}$ with the regular metric.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Consider the set $O = \{(x,y) \in \mathbb{R}^2: xy > 0 \}$, which is open (it's just the union of two open quadrants in the plane, or we see it as $g^{-1}[(0,\rightarrow)]$ for $g(x,y)= xy$ from the plane to $\mathbb{R}$, which is continuous). Then your set $A$ is just the points of $\overline{B}$ that are in $O$ as well, so $A = O \cap \overline{B}$ and by definition of the subspace topology (relative topology) on $\overline{B}$, this just means that $A$ is relatively open in $\overline{B}$.

Your argument that $A$ would not be open doesn't work, because we cannot consider points outside $\overline{B}$ when proving openness in $\overline{B}$ directly. An alternative way to state that $A$ is open in $\overline{B}$ is: for every $x \in A$, there is some $r>0$ such that all points $y$ from $\overline{B}$ (!) such that $d(x,y) < r$, are in $A$. Or in set terms: $\forall x \in A : \exists r>0 : B_r(x) \cap \overline{B} \subset A$.

As to $A'$, your argument can be made to work: for $x = (1,0)$ (which is in $A'$ and in $\overline{B}$), every $r$-ball around it has points like $(1-x,-x)$ for some small $x$, that are in $\overline{B}$ but *not* in $A'$.